# HP PSC 1350 Scanner OS X Lion

Tags: macos, scanning

I just upgraded to OS X Lion. My HP PSC 1350 printer will print but it won't scan. HP's website says to remove, readd, etc, which I tried. It said I could get the generic driver from Apple software update, but nada. How can I scan in Lion with my HP PSC 1350?

Answer (score 1):

I'm so happy! I found it and it works great!

http://support.apple.com/kb/DL907

These are the up-to-date HP Printer drivers appearently. If anyone else is having issues with their printer I'd suggest looking on Apple's website.